# Maven Run gives 'Cannot find symbol' error for 'Path' when run on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

I am having a problem with my Java project. This is a unit test which I click on the IntelliJ Play button to run it. It builds fine, just error when run.

It's saying

> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
> of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)   location: interface
> java.nio.file.Path

Particularly on the code. It highlights **Path**.

```
String payloadJson = Files.readString(Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src/test/java/area.json"));
```

I'm not sure if it is related but I have always worked on this code on a PC (IntelliJ). It works there. I recently moved to a Macbook M1 PRO where it now gives the error.

My imports are as follow:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.*;
```

I am using Oracle OpenJDK 18. Which I set under Project Structure in IntelliJ. I can confirm this when I run `Java --Version`, it shows:

```
% java --version
openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.332.08.1 (build 1.8.0_332-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.332.08.1 (build 25.332-b08, mixed mode)
```

This is getting very hopeless!

Comment: Are you *sure* you are using JDK 18? The method `Path.of(...)` was added in JDK 11. It looks like you are using a version that's older than JDK 11.

Comment: Another possibility: do you have a class named `Path` in your own project? If yes, then rename that class. It's picked up instead of class `java.nio.file.Path` that you intend to use.

Comment: Is that the real path you have located your test data? `src/test/java/area.json` ? If so you should move your test resources to `src/test/resources`...and use getResource("/area.json")... etc.

Comment: @Jesper Yes I'm pretty sure I'm using JDK 18. When I run `java -version` it returns `java version "18.0.2" 2022-07-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: @Jesper The project works on IntelliJ Windows. It's just not working on my Mac (M1 Apple Silicone)

Comment: As @Jesper mentions, it's a >Java 11 method. What you provided in the questions evidently shows a Java 8, not Java 18. You can try running the application in the same terminal that shows Java 18.

Comment: `openjdk version "1.8.0_332"` => This is Java 8 and not Java 18. Don't be confused by the "1.8.0", this is not the same as 18.0.

Answer (score -1):

I am tring the next

1. Install SDK man https://sdkman.io/
2. In the terminal, I installed the next version 8.332.08.1-amzn

> sdk install java 8.332.08.1-amzn

3. Executed the next command when you will finish the step 2.

> sdk use java 8.332.08.1-amzn

4. Execut mvn test

Comment: I am using Mac. Sdkman is for unix

Comment: sdk  permits to use in mac

Comment: Tq but nope, stil does nothing. IntelliJ still gives the same problem `java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: interface java.nio.file.Path`